# How to change a variable for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to create an userform with several comboboxes which take the values from another excel workbooks.

For the moment, my code create the caption label depends on the value of an array that I called "label". For each label I need It open a specific file and takes the combobox values from there. E.g. If I'm in the 1st loop my array value would be "Dirección", then I need the next line of code open an excel workbook named Departamentos.xlsx and take the values from there, if I'm in the 2nd loop, I will need to open another excel workbook called Empresas.xlsx and so on.

This is the code I thought but I don't what's wrong with this because vba returns me a runtime error '91'

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   'Declarando variables
    Dim var As Long               'variable que para el bucle for
    Dim i As Long                 'variable para el bucle for
    Dim label As Variant
    Dim files As Variant

    'Creamos una array que contenga los nombres posibles de label
    label = Array("Dirección", "Empresa", "Area/Planta del suceso")
    files = Array("C:\Users\se72497\Desktop\Departamentos.xlsx", "C:\Users\se72497\Desktop\Empresas.xlsx", "C:\Users\se72497\Desktop\Areas.xlsx")

    For var = 0 To 2
        'Asigna el nombre a las etiquetas
        Controls("label" & var).Caption = label(var)
        set file= Workbooks.Open(files(var))
        'Bucle que recorre cada una de las líneas que existen en la tabla de DEPARTAMENTOS y se añaden a la lista desplegable que se especifica
        For i = 2 To files.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
            Me.Controls("ComboBox" & var).AddItem files.Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 3).Value
        Next i
    Next

    'Se cierran los archivos previamente abiertos
    files.Close
End Sub
```

As you can see I tried to do it using the same method I used with labels and I create an array which contains the path of my files.
Then inside the loop I assign a value for the "file" variable which will change depends on the loop.

**Can someone tell why it doesn work and what can i do instead?**

Comment: Note - why are you closing the file outside the loop?

Comment: Because I just want to open the file to take the values from that file. After that I don't want it to stay open.

Comment: But you should close it *inside* the loop then, right?

Comment: oh yes, I didn't realize that. Thank you

Comment: but if I close the file inside the loop vba returns me an "automation error".

Comment: Where did you move `file.Close` to?

Comment: at the end of the 1st loop.

Comment: Ok, sorry the problem was that I moved "set file" outside the loop, I got it, thank you!

Comment: Not sure how this code is working? `files` is an array so will not have a method call `.close`. `file` on the other hand is the one that should be used to close the file (which BTW you haven't declared.. **Option Explicit** is your friend). `files` will also not have access to your `Sheets`. Have you tried running this code?

Comment: It's also advisable not to use reserved words as variable names (i.e. `files` or `file`)